# How can I disallow `git push` to a specific branch?

Tags: git

Can I set up a repository to allow `git push` only between specific "allowed" branches, and raise an exception if if a `push` is attempted to a "forbidden" branch?

**Example:**

A, B, C are branches.

```
A ==> B // allowed
B ==> A // forbidden
C ==> B // allowed
A ==> A // forbidden
```

Comment: What are A and B, exactly?  A push is different from a merge.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it. A and B are branches. Oh, really, it is different? I am new to git, thanks

Comment: What is your host? Many services (GitHub / GitLab / BitBucket) will allow you to protect branches, though it may be a bit basic for what you're after... You may get what you're after from reading up about hooks, specifically server-side - https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: From your question, it looks like you're just trying to protect the `A` branch... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct. I am using my own personal git server. I just want to avoid that another dev by accident merges data into a branch where it doesn't belong.